# Getting SQL Data wrong?

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

So I have an if statement in PHP to check if a username/email is already in use in the SQL table, but when I am testing it, it keeps saying that the username/email is already in use, even if its not. So I am assuming I did the if statement or the retrieving of data wrong, but I cannot find out which I did wrong. Also, when I am checking if the fields are empty, even if they are it continues, without asking them to fill in all the fields. So I'd be appreciated if someone can tell me what's wrong in these lines of code. Thanks.

```
$sql="SELECT username, email FROM table_name";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($result === FALSE){
}else{
 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}

if (empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['lastname']) || empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password2'])) {
 if(!($_POST['username'] == $row['username']) && ($_POST['email'] == $row['email'])) {

 } else {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    , 'window.alert("That username or email is already in use.")'
    , '</script>';
 }
} else {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    , 'window.alert("Please fill in all the fields.")'
    , '</script>';
}
```

Comment: try echoing the results of the query and $_POST array to the screen: echo $_POST['username']   and echo $row['username']  to visually compare.

Comment: You select all rows in the query, but you only retrieve the first row. You should add a `WHERE` clause and pass the username and email to let the MySQL engine do the search. Focus on getting the validation working first, when you have fully tested that and got it working, move on to the database lookup check. Don't try to solve many problems at once, break it up.

Comment: another thing - your main if statement will only let you in if one of the fields in the form is empty.

Comment: You are selecting **all** usernames and passwords from the database, then you pick only the *first* from it, and if all submitted data is empty you compare it to the (not) submitted data...?! This is completely messed up.

Comment: You also not really have an otherwise unhealthy non-relationship with positively negated `if..else` statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you fetch an array from the database, named `$row`, you have to go through that array and check if username || email is found. (notice I renamed `$row -> $rows`

```
if($result === FALSE){
}else{
 $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password2'])){
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if($row['username'] == $_POST['username'] || $row['email'] == $_POST['email']){
           echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
           , 'window.alert("That username or email is already in use.")'
           , '</script>';
           break;
        }
    }
}
else{
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
    , 'window.alert("Please fill in all the fields.")'
    , '</script>';
}
```

Hope I got it all right, using tablet.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` fetched exactly ***one*** row.

Comment: `isset($var1,$var2,$var3)` instead of `isset($var1) && isset($var2) && isset($var3)`

Comment: I got this error from this?

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/username/public_html/register.php on line 106.

     Line 106 is the foreach($rows as $row){

Comment: Did you change your $row to $rows as I stated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

`SELECT username, email FROM table_name WHERE username="user" AND email="email"`

You need to pass the query column information to compare to the database, or it will return all rows from the database. Therefore, you will always get a return value other than `FALSE`.